# React Native: Open application location settings in Android

Tags: react-native, appsettings

I'm using React Native 0.66.5, and I want to send my users directly to the app's permissions settings, I'm currently using Linking.openSettings() but for Android it is redirecting to the App settings.

I've also tried using react-native-android-open-settings, but it hasn't worked.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: No, I'm not using expo.